# Java Generics Wild Usage and Objects

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am working on practice problems from Introduction to Java Programming, Includes Data Structures, Eleventh Edition, Y. Daniel Liang.

```
19.24  Which of the following can be used to replace YYYYYYYY in the following code?

public class WildCardDemo3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericStack<String> stack1 = new GenericStack<>();
    GenericStack<Object> stack2 = new GenericStack<>();
    stack2.push("Java");
    stack2.push(2);
    stack1.push("Sun");
    add(stack1, stack2);
    WildCardDemo2.print(stack2);
  }

  public static <T> void YYYYYYYY {
    while (!stack1.isEmpty())
      stack2.push(stack1.pop());
  }
}
 A. add(GenericStack<T> stack1, GenericStack<T> stack2)
 B. add(GenericStack<? extends T> stack1, GenericStack<T> stack2)
 C. add(GenericStack<T> stack1, GenericStack<? super T> stack2)
 D. add(GenericStack<T> stack1, GenericStack<Object> stack2)
```

Does it make sense that answer D also works.  I understand stack2 is an object type but I think it should be defined as relates to the type parameter.  Sorry this is a stupid question.

Comment: Why don't you just try them all?

Comment: What do you mean by make scene? As long as it compile, it make sense. It's not uncommon you want to push any type to a stack of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Option A does not compile (at the line `add(stack1, stack2)`) because in this case compiler expects strictly the same generic type for both stacks. Actually, we have `String` and `Object` which are not the same.

Option B compiles. Effectively it becomes to:

```java
<Object> void add(GenericStack</*String*/ ? extends Object> stack1, GenericStack<Object> stack2)
```

`String` extends `Object`. Wild card restriction is satisfied.

Option C compiles. Effectively it becomes to:

```java
<String> void add(GenericStack<String> stack1, GenericStack</*Object*/? super String> stack2)
```

The `Object` is superclass for all classes in Java including `String`. Wild card restriction is satisfied.

Option D compiles. Effectively it becomes to:

```java
<String> void add(GenericStack<String> stack1, GenericStack<Object> stack2)
```

The `Object` class is wider than `String`. That's why `GenericStack<Object> stack2` can contain String values from the `GenericStack<String> stack1`.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, D does it work. The only one that doesn't work is A.
You can check it yourself by writing the code and running it.